# How do i list volumes and volume tag for a given EC2 server in AWS CLI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

How do I list volumes and volume tag for a given EC2 server in AWS CLI

```
aws ec2 describe-tags --filters "Name=tag:volume-id,Values=vol-xxxxxx" --region us-east-2 --profile xxxxx --output=text
```

Comment: `For a given ec2 server` what does this mean because your provided command does not have anything specified attribute  for existing instance

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `resource-id` into the `filters` as explained in [describe-tags](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-tags.html) docs.

Answer (score 0):

This command list volume and its tags associated with ec2 instance.

**Assuming you already know the instance id**

```
aws ec2 describe-volumes --filters Name=attachment.instance-id,Values=i-xxxxxxxxxxx
```